# Reactjs Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm-install

I was working on a reactjs app on my linux machine, it all worked good there.

When i tried another machine macos I am getting the following error:

Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/Users/ioi/Desktop/Work/winova/gf-t.fg_frontend/src/index.js: Unexpected token (6:16)

while line 6 is : 
`ReactDOM.render(<AppRoutes/>, document.getElementById("index"));`

Any idea what this would be? I did npm install initially so I have all the libraries installed for the app to run.

Whole index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import AppRoutes from './routes';
require('../src/assets/styles/main.scss');
console.log("I am being called index.js...");
ReactDOM.render(<AppRoutes/>, document.getElementById("index"));
```

Also to note: I am using webpack 4.8 for building the app.

Comment: Show us the lines 5 and 7 as well.

Comment: Make sure you're using a node version >=8

Comment: @PraveenKumar updated my question u can have a look

Comment: i am using node version 6.11.4 on this machine where the app is crashinig

Comment: try recreating your component on codesandbox just to be sure there's bugs and that it's an environment issue https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: @Pixelomo it must be environment issue but I just dont know what, the code is identical!

Comment: you might need Node 8+...

Comment: i installed nodejs v8.11.1 and still same error

Comment: i think i need to install webpack

Comment: installed webpack, nodejs latest version, nothing works!